# Recommendations for books on mathematical logic

Tags: logic, book-recommendation

What are some good introductory books on mathematical logic?

I’m currently working through Russell’s *Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy*.

I’ve seen Kleene’s *Mathematical Logic* pop up, is this an approachable text?

Comment: There are lots of recommendations out there but I particularly recommend *Fundamentals of mathematical logic* by Hinman. It is lengthy but for a good reason: everything is worked out carefully so that if you're new to the subject you won't feel like it's being hand-wavy and it's readable unlike Shoenfield (although it's a great book too). It covers propositional logic, first-order logic, and more. It's very comprehensive so you can read about set theory or decidability, or even some model theory if you want to.